# getElementById(...) is null. Works fine in Firebug

Tags: javascript, html

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.
No idea why I am getting this error.  Works fine in Firebug.

```
function init() {
updateClock ();
};


function updateClock ( )
{
  var currentTime = new Date ( );
  var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
  var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
  var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );
  // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
  currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
  currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;
  // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
  var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";
  // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
  currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
  // Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
  currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;
  // Compose the string for display
  currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + " " + timeOfDay; 
  // Update the time display
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = currentTimeString;
}

currentTimeString = "";
window.addEventListener("load", init(), false);
```

Here is how it is imlemented in the html:

```
<body>
<p id="time">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you  provide a http://jsfiddle.net where we can reproduce the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener("load", init(), false);
```

This line calls `init` **immediately** and passes the result to `addEventListener` (just like any other function call).

You want to pass the function itself, without calling it.

Answer (score 4):

change the line

```
window.addEventListener("load", init(), false);
```

to

```
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

the reason is that you call the `init()` function in your original code (and the return value is passed to addEventListener). You need to pass the function init (variable) instead.

Comment: You should explain _why_.